# Reviewing posts flagged as low quality

Tags: discussion

I sometimes get confused about what I should do in the review queues when a post is flagged as low quality.
[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84455/7944) is the example I'm currently thinking of.

Whilst the answer isn't great, and doesn't really answer the question, it's not hopelessly wrong either. I would normally either just ignore or possibly downvote something like that.

What confuses me is that the review queue gives me three options:

1. Looks OK -- well it's not really okay so I don't want to select that option.
2. Edit -- Editing will not improve this answer.
3. Delete -- Seems extreme. I normally only flag for deletion if something is offensive or clearly spam.

I suppose the simple answer is just to skip it, but is that shirking responsibility? What is the threshold for not being low quality and clicking 'looks OK'? What is the threshold for being worthy of deletion? I was wondering what other people thought about these options and what the best course of action is in a case like this.

Comment: This is an issue almost exclusive to answers too.  With low quality questions, I can flag them as needing additional information/clarification, and the options are much more cut and dry.  There is a lot more ambiguity when it comes to reviewing low quality answers.

Comment: Note that some posts are *automatically* flagged as low quality *by the system* based on certain criteria, so there are some chances that the post is actually not that low quality (i.e. not flagged manually by any user). Also, depending on how strict/lenient the user's reviewing policy, it's okay to choose "Looks OK" (it's an attempt to answer) while downvoting it (it's a bad answer though).